# OpenCV Xcode 9.2: "ld: library not found for -lopencv_core.3.3.1"

Tags: xcode, opencv

Im getting this error message:

> ld: library not found for -lopencv_core.3.3.1

But I linked OpenCV in "Header Search Paths": 
`_/usr/local/include_` and in Library Search Paths: `_/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.0_1/lib_` (Compiler wrote it by himself, I wrote: `_/usr/local/lib_`)

Although i added all the frameworks i need in "Other Linker Flags" and put them also in "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" (General).

I really don't know ho to solve this problem. Is it possible that the version of the opencv_core, he wants to include, could be a problem? He is searching for version: **3.3.1** but I included **opencv_core3.4.0**. How is it possible that he can find this version?

I tried to unistalled *OpenCV* and *Xcode* but that won't solve the problem.

I hope that you guys can help me with that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved the problem.

For those who want to know the Solution:

- I created a new Xcode Project
- Included all the needed OpenCV Frameworks (Right Click on Project)
- Added the Header Search Path: */usr/local/include*

After that I started the application without an error. The library search path was automatically added by the compiler.